# Can someone post example for percentile in solr

Tags: solrj, percentile

The refernces I see are in the form of HTTP request. But how is it in code example?

Maybe this syntax:
        search.setParam("facet", true);
        search.setParam("percentiles", true);
        search.setParam("percentiles.field", "networkTime");
        search.setParam("percentiles.requested.percentiles", "25,50,75");
        search.setParam("percentiles.lower.fence", "0");
        search.setParam("percentiles.upper.fence", "1000000");
        search.setParam("percentiles.gap", "10");
        search.setParam("percentiles.averages", true);

Or this syntax?
        search.setParam("facet", true);
        search.setParam("facets.stats.percentiles", true);
        search.setParam("facets.stats.percentiles.field", "networkTime");
        search.setParam("f.networkTime.stats.percentiles.requested", "25,50,75");
        search.setParam("f.networkTime.stats.percentiles.lower.fence", "0");
        search.setParam("f.networkTime.stats.percentiles.upper.fence", "1000000");
        search.setParam("f.networkTime.stats.percentiles.gap", "10");
        search.setParam("facets.stats.percentiles.averages", true);

Thanks!